# Почему в переносе строк появляются лишние пробелы? Discord.py (Python)

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

Я делаю бота, где есть сообщение Embed. И в сообщение Embed будет список участников сервера. Но я не понимаю, почему в списке есть лишние пробелы?

```
count = 1


for user in users_s:
    usere = await bot.fetch_user(int(user))
    list_ += f"**{count}. {usere.name} - {sorted_value[user]['balance']}**\n"
    count += 1

emb = discord.Embed(
    title="**Balance of users**",
    url="",
    color=discord.Color.purple(),
    description=list_
)


await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

В коде ошибок нет, но отправляет бот сообщение странно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В сообщении есть лишнии как сказать "\n" (перенос строк).

Comment: а если убрать `\n`?

Comment: То они все в одну строку собираются

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена, я понял что строка не помещается в сообщение. Поэтому бывает перенос строк. Чтобы решить это, я убрал жирный шрифт (в начале "**" и в конце строки). И поставил жирный шрифт только на имя участника и его баланс. Походу он считает ** буквой и переносит строку.